# Shortcut to open the Goto window in file open/save dialogues WITH the equivalent to path added

Tags: snow-leopard, finder

When you have a file open/save prompt box open, you can hit the <kbd>/</kbd> key to open a GoTo dialouge to navigate via the file path.

**Is there a shortcut that does this action but automatically adds the `./`**

ie. hitting the shortcut would open a box looking like this:
[image: Goto Box in Open/Save prompts]

*(where normally the period at the beginning is missing)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to delete the automatically added `/` in the beginning. The Go To box works from the current directory in the background.

For example if I open my home folder and press /, the Go To box opens with a `/` already there. If I want to work from the current directory (`./`), i.e., `home`, I just have to delete that `/`.

Now, if I type `./Desktop` and press enter, or just `Desktop` and press enter, the result would be the same.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo!